# ¿Cómo hago para eliminar los corchetes de más dentro de una lista en un diccionario?

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, diccionarios

estaba practicando un ejercicio sobre diccionario y se me vino un problema. Los códigos que use fueron estos:

```
diccionario={
    "dólar": [166.6, 170.0, 180.1, 190.9, 120.1],
    "yen": [1.2, 1.9, 2.1, 5.0, 0.9],
    "euro": [174.34, 180.1, 200.5, 190.3, 150.0]
}

departamento = [25000.0]

nuevo_dic = {"cotiz_dolar": [],
             "cotiz_yen": [],
             "cotiz_euro": []
             }

for i in range (0,3):
  nuevo_valor=[x*departamento[0] for x in diccionario[list(diccionario.keys())[i]]]
  nuevo_dic[list(nuevo_dic.keys())[i]].append(nuevo_valor)

print(nuevo_dic)
```

Una vez usado el comando print, me aparece este resultado.

```
{'cotiz_dolar': [[4165000.0, 4250000.0, 4502500.0, 4772500.0, 3002500.0]], 'cotiz_yen': [[30000.0, 47500.0, 52500.0, 125000.0, 22500.0]], 'cotiz_euro': [[4358500.0, 4502500.0, 5012500.0, 4757500.0, 3750000.0]]}
```

La cuestión es que hay doble corchetes en cada lista del diccionario. Tiene alguna idea de cómo eliminar el corchete de más para cada una.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes cambiar la funcion `.append` por `.extend`  con ese cambio ya eliminarías el doble corchetes y quedaría plano los registros.

Quedando asi:

```
{'cotiz_dolar': [4165000.0, 4250000.0, 4502500.0, 4772500.0, 3002500.0],
 'cotiz_yen': [30000.0, 47500.0, 52500.0, 125000.0, 22500.0],
 'cotiz_euro': [4358500.0, 4502500.0, 5012500.0, 4757500.0, 3750000.0]}
```

Aquí te dejo este artículo donde te deja claro como funcionan los dos: https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/python-lista-append-vs-python-lista-extend/

Comment: Estupendo sería explicar la diferencia entre uno y otro método.

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta y deje el link...